# How do i find where my apache2 is installed in my centos server?

Tags: filesystems, centos, apache-http-server

What methods can I use to find where my apache2 is installed on my centos server? btw, i have cpanel installed.

I want to edit my sites-available entries and point one of my domains to another directory on the server, but i can't seem to find where this is installed. i did a **locate apache2** but i get so many entries. why are there so many anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Linux programs use shared folders designated for different tasks. For example, programs which follow the standard (such as Apache) will put their configuration files in the `/etc` folder. Specifically, `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. On Cent OS it'll be in the later. You shouldn't need to know the location of the binary but if you do then just use `find / -name httpd`. Also, most systems put the default website in `/var/www` FYI.

Comment: so all the 3rd party installed apps go into the /etc folder?

Comment: For the most part. I'm sure you can find exceptions to this which don't follow the standard.